# C#- Print an additional message to the the actual specflow error

Tags: c#, automated-tests, nunit, hook, specflow

I'm trying to add an additional message to the the actual specflow error message using the AfterStep hook as below but it is not working, can someone please suggest a better way.

```
[AfterStep]
public void AfterStep()
{
    if (this.scenarioContext.ScenarioExecutionStatus == ScenarioExecutionStatus.TestError)
    {
        var stepName = this.scenarioContext.StepContext.StepInfo.Text;
        var stepTable = this.scenarioContext.StepContext.StepInfo.Table;
        var errorLength = this.scenarioContext.TestError.Message.Length;
        this.scenarioContext.TestError.Message.Insert(errorLength, "\r\n Failed at Step: " + stepName + "\r\n" + stepTable + "\r\n");
    }
}
```

I have tried to throw another custom exception for printing my the additional message from inside the AfterStep hook but that changes the original stack trace.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit your question to [include code, data and error messages as text, not images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/16563198).

Answer (score 1):

This answer is not exactly what you're asking, but I hope it gets to the spirit of what you're trying to achieve.

My preferred practice in this scenario -- wanting to add more context about failures -- is to use the [SpecFlow Output API](https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/outputapi/outputapi.html).

The instructions in long-form are at the link above, but you can inject `ISpecFlowOutputHelper` into your step definitions classes. This will then allow you to write additional lines in your SpecFlow output at a given step.

Typically, I'll use a `try/catch` statement to catch an exception that happens during step execution, then I'll use `ISpecFlowOutputHelper`'s `WriteLine` method to print some additional information.

This allows you to print the context in the step where it happens, which I find is useful when reviewing failed scenarios.

Comment: This is nice, Will this print the additional information along with the error message or in the Standard output?

Answer (score 0):

I implemented this to fix it. This prints the message I wanted to print and also shows the actual stack trace.

```
[AfterStep]
        public void AfterStep()
        {
            if (this.scenarioContext.ScenarioExecutionStatus == ScenarioExecutionStatus.TestError)
            {
                var errorMessage = this.scenarioContext.TestError.Message;
                var stepName = this.scenarioContext.StepContext.StepInfo.Text;
                var stepTable = this.scenarioContext.StepContext.StepInfo.Table;
                var exception = this.scenarioContext.TestError.GetBaseException();
                exception.GetType().GetField("_message", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).SetValue(exception, "Failed at Step: \r\n" + stepName + "\r\n" + stepTable + "\r\n Actual Error: \r\n" + errorMessage);
                var ex = ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(exception);
                ex.Throw();
            }
        }
```